# PHP fsockopen client doesn't receive sent data

Tags: php, fsockopen, php-socket

I have the following (stripped-down) piece of code:

```
function curl_request_async($url, $params)
{
    foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
        $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
    }
    $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

    $parts=parse_url($url);

    $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
        isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
        $errno, $errstr, 30);
    fwrite($fp, "$type ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n");

    $bytes_written = fwrite($fp, $post_string);
    var_dump($bytes_written, strlen($post_string));
    // fread($fp, 1);
    // fflush($fp);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The problem with this code is that I found no evidence the request reached the server called. The line `var_dump($bytes_written, strlen($post_string));` outputted `int(493) int(493)`, so it should have received all data, yet it didn't.

If I uncomment `fread($fp, 1);` it works without a problem. That could be working solution, but it doesn't seem to make sense. There has to be a better way!

My question then is two-fold: why does `fread($fp, 1);` fix my problem and is there a better solution?

Comment: Do not attempt to write your own http client in PHP unless you are extremely competent in both technologies and have a few months spare to work on this full time. Just enumerating the faults in the code you've presented would go way beyond the scope of an answer here. Use curl. I know the PHP documentation is poor, but the C library docs are a bit better, and it works.

Comment: @symcbean its not that hard, if you want to support httpS and content-encoding negotiation and redirects and content-length and all that fancy stuff, sure, but if you're just going for a simple http GET client, its not really hard. GET url\r\nheader1\r\nheader2\r\n\r\nbody  ~

Comment: @hansherik: looking at the code you provided it seems to beyond your abilities. The TCP socket is not the hard bit. The example you have provided above is even wider off the mark than Lex's code.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is probably that you wrote the server code in PHP, and you dont have ignore_user_abort=true by default (see http://php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort ), so when you close the connection, your server stop executing your php code, thus fread(fp,1) fix your problem - connection dont close before php start writing a response

you can use this code to make a server to test if its actually connecting or not -

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$sck=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
if($sck===FALSE){
    die('socket_create failed!');
}
if(!socket_set_block($sck)){
    die("socket_set_block failed!");
}
if(!socket_bind($sck, '0.0.0.0',1337)){
    die("FAILED to bind to port 1337");
}
if(!socket_listen($sck,0)){
    die("socket_listen failed!");
}
$fullFile='';
while((print('listening for connections!'.PHP_EOL)) && false!==($conn=socket_accept($sck))){
    echo "new connection!".PHP_EOL;
    echo "generating crypto iv..";

    while(false!==($buffi=socket_recv($conn,$buff,1024,MSG_WAITALL))){
        if($buffi===0){
            break;//socket_recv's way of
            //saying that the connection closed,
            //apparently. the docs say it should return
            // false, but it doesn't, it just infinitely returns int(0).
            // at least on windows 7 x64 sp1.
        }
        $fullFile.=$buff;
        echo "recieved ".strlen($fullFile)." bytes...".PHP_EOL;
        $buff='';//do i need to clear it? or wiill recv do it for me?
    }
    echo "all bytes recieved (i guess, todo, socket_last_error confirm).";
    echo PHP_EOL;var_dump($fullFule);
    echo "done!".PHP_EOL;
}

die("should never reach this code...");
```

it will make a netcat-style server on http://127.0.0.1:1337

Answer (score 0):

fread needs two parameters: a resource and a length number of bytes to read.
Right now you are only reading 1 byte. `fread($fp, 1);`

If you want to read the complete result, loop it until readed completely:

```
while(!feof($fp)){
    echo fread($fp, 128);
}
```